# Algorithm for mapping connections

Tags: java, algorithm

I think this is something that has probably been solved before and if I had the proper mathematical vocabulary I could probably just google it. I'm writing an application that generates code for micro controllers like the Arduino and part of this process is mapping the connections required by a device like a sensor to the micro controller itself.

The problem is not all the connections on the micro controller are equally capable, some can only do digital IO, some can do digital IO + analog out, some can do digital IO + analog in, and some can do both digital and Analog IO. So if for example I were to run out of purely digital IO connections and required more, I could still use for example a Digital IO + analog In pin. But if that were the only digital IO + analog in pin and then I were to actually need that functionality for another connection, then i would need to move it to a different kind of pin.

So basically I need an algorithm that can create this kind of mapping if one is at all possible. The problem is a bit like that kids game with shaped blocks and corresponding holes, some shapes can fit in multiple holes, some cant, can you figure out if you can put all the given blocks into holes?

Comment: Looks like you came up with a satisfactory answer for this case, but in general the Google term you need is "Assignment Problem".

Answer (score 0):

Okay it wasn't as bad as I thought, I solved it on my own.

So we have four categories of functionality (DIO+AIO, DIO+AI, DIO+AO, DIO only)

1)Assign any requested connection for the most functional pin (DIO+AIO), if theres not enough, its not gonna work

2)Assign as many requested connection as you can to pins that only provide required fucntionaility, youll end up with 3 groups of overflow. (overflow of the 4th is a failure.)

3)AI connections cannot use AO pins and viceversa so they're both competing for free AIO pins at this point, if there's more overflowed AI & AO connections then available AIO pins, its a failure, otherwise assign the overflowed AI & AO connections to AIO pins.

4)Assign any overflowed digital connections into free AI and AO pins, if theres not enough its a failure.

5)If you got here you should have coherent map of connections!